# Using regular expressions to add numbers using find and replace in Notepad++

Tags: replace, find, notepad++

I have a SPROC which is having the multiple instances of string Say '#TRML_CLOSE'.

I want to make them to be concatenated with a sequence of numbers.

Eg:
Search and find string '#TRML_CLOSE'

And

Replace the 1st Instance with '#TRML_CLOSE_1', 
Replace the 2nd Instance with '#TRML_CLOSE_2', 
Replace the 3nd Instance with '#TRML_CLOSE_3',

and so on.

How do I achieve this in Notepad++ using expressions.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the extent you can script Notepad++, but I do know you can throw together a quick JavaScript snippet to do what you want. http://jsfiddle.net/x4eSr/

Just go to the JS fiddle, and hit the button.

```
document.getElementById("btn").onclick = function() {
    var elm = document.getElementById("txt");
    var val = elm.value;
    var cnt = 1;
    val = val.replace(/#TRML_CLOSE(?!=[_])/g, function(m) {
        return m + "_" + cnt++;
    });
    elm.value = val;
};
```

Using JavaScript's string.replace(regex, function(){}) which calls the function on each match and a globally incremented "cnt" variable.

Comment: I do not see an option to do scripting in Notepadd++ .... Even If I get any another tool with Search and repalce which does the same would be good. any suggestions?. I saw there are some options in 'TextPad' app to do regular expressions but I am not able to get them working. The incremental replace is just not working.